# Weighted random bearing for wandering point

Tags: javascript, random, geospatial

```
var latlon = new LatLon(50,-0.075);
setInterval(function(){
    latlon = latlon.destinationPoint(randomBetween(0,360),0.001);
},1000);
```

Here is my very basic wandering point. It creates a geospatial point then moves one metre in a random direction every second. However, this is too random. How can I give my wandering point some direction so that it actually moves somewhere? Are the any good examples out there of a wandering geospatial point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store last wandering coefficient (as I undestand that would be `randomBetween(...)` value) in a variable, and next time use a weighted average of this value and new random value.

```
var latlon = new LatLon(50,-0.075);
var oldValue = randomBetween(0,360);
var weights = [0.5, 0.5];  // Here you can influece the level of 'randomness'. 
// Just make sure to weights sum up to 1
setInterval(function(){
    var newValue = oldValue * weights[0] + randomBetween(0,360) * weights[1];
    latlon = latlon.destinationPoint(newValue, 0.001);
    oldValue = newValue;
},1000);
```